# Bigcomerce GLOABL variable not working in custom panel file

Tags: templates, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I am trying to display current logged in customer's email address in custom panel with in JavaScript. but it is not working. The tag m using is %%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerEmail%%. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The global var you are using is not correct `%%GLOBAL_CustomerEmailAddress%%`